# Creating a list using the last element of each line in a text file

Tags: python

I'm a bit of a newbie in programming. Currently I'm trying to create lists by reading a text file. Also without importing any modules.

I basically want to put each category into their own list.

This is how I started:

```
def lecturer():
    lecturer_info = open('timetables.txt', 'r')
    line = lecturer_info.readline().split(',')

    while line != '':
        lecturer_info = line.split(',')
        full_name = lecturer_info[-1].split()

    print('full_name')
```

But I'm currently getting an error...
"lecturer_info = line.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Any ideas on how to fix this, or an alternate way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: you use for loop to iterate over the list and each element will contain line from txt file. You call the split on the elements of list and not the list itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is close to yours with some corrections:

```
def lecturer():
    lecturer_info = open('timetables.txt', 'r')
    lines = lecturer_info.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        lst = line.strip().split(',')
        full_name = lst[-1]
        print(full_name)

    lecturer_info.close()
```

output:

```
Ada Log
Ena Blue
```

Comment: One suggestion: -using *with* to open the file and it'll close automatically, when ops. done:   with open('timetables.txt', 'r') as fin: ....

Comment: @DanielHao. Yes, of course.  I was trying to change OP's code as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `file.readlines()` to loop over each line in the text file, then simply split each individual row by `,` and call the last index.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file.readlines():
        row = row.split(',')
        print(row[-1].split())
```

Output

```
['Ada', 'Log']
['Ena', 'Blue']
```

Comment: To improve the performance, we can use `rindex(",")` to get the last index of `,`. Then using it for extracting the last item of each row: `item = row[row.rindex(",") + 1:]`

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from your trying to use the split method on a list, split can only be used on strings. The variable "line" is assigned to a list because split() returns a list.